# Click on image that opens the users mail, to send to my email adress

Tags: image, email, sendmail, html-email

I want to make an image once it has been clicked on, to open the users mail, with my email address in the message ready to send

As seen in this website when you click contact - http://downgram.com/

Comment: Please explain properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's best to use plain ol' HTML to achieve this in email.

Email client opened with your address pre filled:

```
<a href="mailto:yourEmail@domain.com"><img src="yourImage.jpg"></a>
```

With email address and subject pre filled:

```
<a href="mailto:yourEmail@domain.com?subject=Hello"> ...
```

With email address, subject, and body pre filled:

```
<a href="mailto:yourEmail@domain.com?subject=Hello&body=How are you doing?"> ...
```

Please be aware that this will **at least** pre fill the email address. The subject line and body will depend on the user agent's support and it's not something you can "fix"

Comment: Just saw your edit. For what you want to do, the first code example will work. I'll just leave the other two examples in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<FORM Action="mailto:someaddress@example.com?Subject=Some+Test+Subject" METHOD="POST">
<INPUT type="image" src="button.jpg"/>
</FORM>
```